# Regex capture consecutive numbers in a pattern

Tags: regex, numbers

Trying to extract the numbers from a string of pattern:
`<Some Alphanumeric> <numbers> X <numbers> <Some Alphanumeric>`

e.g.
`I 00 Crazy 060 X 0140 08 Dance 47`

should extract the numbers `060` and `0140` and the text `I 00 Crazy` and `08 Dance 47`

I'm using the following Regex: 
`(.*)(\d{1,3})\s*(x|X)\s*(\d{1,4})(.*)`

However this isn't working on the first number preceding the X, it's only capturing `0` instead of `060` but captures the second number `0140` correctly.

`\d{1,3}` should be a greedy capture of digits between 1 and 3 in length - so what am I missing here?

Comment: You need lazy matching with the first group - `(.*?)(\d{1,3})\s*([xX])\s*(\d{1,4})(.*)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work,

```
(.*)\b(\d{1,3})\s*(x|X)\s*(\d{1,4})(.*)
```

Here, `\b` asserts position at a word boundary `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`

Comment: It works but I'm not clear on why it was needed in the 1st number and not the second.

Comment: Because `(.*)` would consume everyting before your next capture, i.e `\d{1,3})`, even the spaces. Thus even this would work `(.*)\s+(\d{1,3})\s*(x|X)\s*(\d{1,4})(.*)`

Comment: Also in the second one you explicitly say that there is an `(x|X)` before your next capture group,hence it works. There was no separator in the first one.

Comment: Okay so why not `\s+` instead of `\b` - trying to understand the pro's con's of the approach.

Comment: There is one question, can I make the space optional? e.g. `Text04Text5x6Test` so it extract 5 ? With the `\b` it won't do it, and if I use `\s*` it the original example will fail.

Comment: Okay I think I got it, use lookbehind `(?<=\D)(\d{1,3})`, that would be a better answer which can handle a space or not

Comment: Yes, there are many ways sometimes to do the same thing in regex, and look behind gives you a better control, yes